# What is wrong with this angularJS script? Expressions within the controller are not evaluating

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to reproduce an example from the O'Reilly book (page 23.)

Here's the link: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/fqGnSO?p=preview

Notice that the expression added outside the controller scope works, yet the ones inside don't. Also, I can't manage to toggle the list items.

Comment: neither works at the moment. you should just define `menuState` on the scope, i.e. `$scope.menuState = {};` and it'll work.

Comment: You also need to add ng-show='menuState.show' to your ul tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting a Javascript error because `$scope.menustate` is undefined when you try to set `show` on it. Change your first line of the controller to:

```
$scope.menuState = { show: false };
```

As far as your list, it isn't toggling because you never told it to. You have the variable, but you still need to add the toggling hook into the html.

```
<ul ng-show="menuState.show">
```

That should do it.